# Zero-truncated Poisson distribution in glmmTMB

Tags: r, glmm, glmmtmb

I'm trying to use a zero-truncated Poisson GLMM using the R package `glmmTMB`.

The documentation for this package says that zero-truncated Poisson can be specified, but doesn't include the exact syntax.

Does anyone know what to specify in `family=` for this distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears in the Exanples section help page for the `glmmTMB` function from the package of the same name. It appears to be what you asked for:

```
## Hurdle Poisson model
(m3 <- glmmTMB(count~spp + mined + (1|site), 
  zi=~spp + mined, 
  family=list(family="truncated_poisson", link="log"), Salamanders))
```

There's also a discussion of some issues with truncated distributions in the vignette.